# How to disable language autodetection in Word style?

Tags: microsoft-word, language

I want to make style to type programming code in Word.

Unfortunately, Word tries to guess (human) language and do some other wrong things.

How to disable? There is an option, but it is dimmed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "Do not check spelling or grammar" option instead.  See the answer #2 [here:](https://superuser.com/questions/699998/can-i-use-a-character-style-to-turn-off-spell-checking-for-program-code-within-a)

The VBA solution works for me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although the language dialog box suggests that you might be able to set "Detect language automatically" for a range or for a style, in fact the property can only be toggled at the application level. If you are seeing language-specific behaviour in text marked, directly or via a style, as "Do not check spelling or grammar" then it is more likely to be something to do with the Primary Editing language or installation language.